# Getting Error "LoadError: cannot load such file -- celluloid/current" while running rake db:create on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, celluloid

I am trying to setup new project which is in rails 6. When I am trying to create DB by running rake db:create, it gives me below error. Here is the complete trace.

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- celluloid/current
/home/rakesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/home/rakesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/rakesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:89:in `register'
/home/rakesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/rakesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:44:in `require'
/home/rakesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
/home/rakesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/home/rakesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
/home/rakesh/workspace/config/application.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/rakesh/workspace/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/home/rakesh/workspace/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/rakesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/rake-13.0.3/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/rakesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/home/rakesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I have tried multiple things to resolve the issue. e.g. - updating "private_pub" gem and ruby version etc.Any help would be highly appreciated.